Redirect to a different port in IIS
Good afternoon
I have a site in IIS which I also connected to a domain, say our domain name is x.net And the site port is 8044
x.net:8044 is working fine from a public IP address, however what I'd like to do is when typing x.net from public, I want to redirect it to x.net:8044, I've tried all kinds of AI tools and they all responded with the URL rewrite, I've done almost all of them with no luck. What am I missing?
Thanks for your help in advance. Kind Regards,
I created a rewrite URL rule
I also tried reverse proxy settings which didn't work

Is there any specific reason that you need to use port 8044? If you stick to port 80/443, there isn't any need of URL redirection.

Thanks for the comment. It's been built on 8044, that's why I'm using the port 8044. Thank you

Use url rewrite can meet your needs, what are the rule you tried? you can use the following rules as a reference:
<rules>
  <rule name="Redirect to Port 8044" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^80$" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:8044/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
 


Hello samwu,
Thanks a bunch for your help.
Here's what it looks like but unfortunately when I type x.com it says this site can't be reached:












Can you provide the details of your test? I need to further analyze your problem.
